# LCD 4x20 display malfunction after ESD, Recover?

Tags: arm, lcd, esd, ce

I have a device with 4x20 generic LCD display controlled by arm STR750 processor which is working well.

According to *IEC EN 61000-6-4 standart criteia B* display of device should be recovered in a while after any static discharge. ESD tests are done with 4kV per second to contact and 8kV per second for 10 seconds to glass surface of LCD and my LCD fails on both. My LCD chars displays wrongly and garbled ter a static discharge -my processor works normally-.

It keeps wrong display until end-user reset the ARM processor but *IEC EN 61000-6-4 standard criteria B* says it should be recovered without user interaction. So I should recover that malfunction with STR750 arm processor. Simple reinit of LCD makes it work good again.

How can I understand any malfunction occurs on my LCD that makes wrongly display by ARM processor? And Is there any robust way to recover it? I can sense it by STR750 arm processor with readback just after a write to LCD register for everytime but it is not robust.

I am asking for a method or procedure that helps me to write C code to my arm processor or a hardware trick for recovery after LCD malfunction because LCD is generic and have no info about ESD so I cant make any changes on LCD.

Comment: How long does the reinit process take? If it's fast enough to not be visible, maybe you could just do it every few seconds?

Comment: **CE has no standards! It has directives.** You **have to** comply to the directive. You **may** use standards to make plausible you satisfied the directives.

Comment: The IEC EN 61000-6-4 **standard** says if you **may apply** Performance criterion C (Temporary loss of function is allowed, provided the function is selfrecoverable or can be restored by the operation of the controls.) then your application satisfies this standard, because (I think) resetting the device equals "can be restored by the operation of the controls"

Comment: @Huisman just edit the question according to your correction. So you are saying the case that we faced does not prevent CE certification?

Comment: @Justin The test lab said, 1 minute is OK. I though your suggestion at the begining of the case but display have user interface and refreshing the page rapidly discomforts the usage.

Comment: What LCD? In what mode you are using it? Can you rewrite chars to it continuously?

Comment: If you have a power button, maybe a quick press on it could reset the screen where a longer press would be required to turn it off.

Comment: @HakanUlusoy CE is basically about safety. The performance criteria the product will have to satisfy depends on the **intended use** of the product. However, people sometimes use their index finger to read. If they would do that with this product, they may initiate an ESD, making the product annoying to use. So, from a selling perspective, I would still try to at least satisfy to criteria B

Comment: @Justme It is a 4x20 mono LCD module-chinese production no datasheet. Yes I write the chars continuously about device status. Thats why when LCD failed, garbled chars coming. I think LCD module processor is reset when ESD happens.

Comment: @HakanUlusoy so basic HD44780 compatible? Do you use it 4-bit or 8-bit mode? Where are the schematics and code we can look at?

Comment: @Justme Yes it is. I am using 4-bit mode. I dont have permissions to share shematics but I can say I am using P2 port of STR750. 
P2.14->LCD.4(RS)
P2.13->LCD.5(R/W)
P2.12->LCD.6(E)
P2.08->LCD.11(D4)
P2.09->LCD.12(D5) 
P2.10->LCD.13(D6) 
P2.11->LCD.14(D4).
And I found the codes from arduino forums but I lost the link :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ESD pulse causes the LCD 4-bit nybble based comms to go out of sync by a nybble. If you perform the sequence to resync it every time you update the display it will solve your problem.

Comment: What you mean by "resync it".

Comment: Set the display to 8-bit mode and then back to 4-bit mode, and the MCU and LCD will again agree which nybble is which. The proper init sequence how to do that so it works every time is in the HD44780 datasheets.

Comment: I got your point but if I send init sequence I lost address counter.

Comment: No you don't if you don't do operations that would change it so there is no problem. And you can set the address counter yourself at any time so there is no problem either. And if the comms were already out of sync then you already have lost the address counter and have garbage characters so the whole screen must be redrawn.

Comment: I dont make any adress change operation but when I send 0x03-0x03-0x02 (makes 4bit mode again) display shows garbage chars at several addresses until I redrawn all lines. If I do resync everytime it creates a bad view even if there is no ESD

Comment: But that is not the correct sequence to change properly to 8-bit mode and back to 4-bit mode. Depending on what timing you use it may leave the display in 8-bit mode. Copy the sequence from datasheet, don't invent shortcuts.

Comment: 0x03-(wait>4.1ms)-0x03-(wait>100us)-0x03-0x03(8bit) 0x03-(wait>4.1ms)-0x03-(wait>100us)-0x03-0x02 (4bit) thats what datasheet said. I did this. Still problem.
First 0x03 good. Second 0x03 random chars in 1. and 3. line. Third 0x03 rewrite the screen but some chars are wrong.

Comment: You did set the cursor position and rewrote the whole screen, right?

Comment: No I just did 0x03-(wait>4.1ms)-0x03-(wait>100us)-0x03-0x03(8bit) 0x03-(wait>4.1ms)-0x03-(wait>100us)-0x03-0x02 (4bit).
after this sequence screen display almost same screen but some chars are wrong, duplicate of buttom line.

Comment: Due to the extra ESD spike causing a nybble send, you can't guarantee what data has been written or what command has been written, so rewrite whole screen after getting back to 4-bit mode.

Comment: It is not about ESD, when I resync even if there is no ESD the wrong chars appear. I have to resync the LCD even if I write only one char unless I sense the curruption with ESD. Is there any way to understand LCD lost its nybble? So I can resync after it.

Comment: You can try to read character data or address pointer back of course, to see if it matches. Post the LCD driver code will you? Random forum post code is rarely robust enough for serious work, besides you might have copyright issues using someone's code depending on the licence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105480/discussion-between-hakan-ulusoy-and-justme).